# webpack bundle throws error on IE11 because of just one node package 'crypto-js'

Tags: reactjs, webpack, internet-explorer-11, cryptojs, babel-loader

I am new to webpack and babel. I am developing a react app with custom webpack and babel set up.

I had added react-app-polyfill to this application and it had worked well on IE11.
But after installing crypto-js, when I run webpack server locally on IE11, webpack bundle throws an error `expected ')'`

I googled this error and found out that this happens with the default parameter, which is es6 feature ( I assume probably crypto-js was written with some of es6 features).
So I removed exclude node_modules in the `webpack-local-config.js` file to transpile node packages.

from

```
module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    }]
  }
```

to

```
module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      include: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/crypto-js')
      ],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    }]
  }
```

didn't work so tried this

```
module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    }]
  }
```

But these tries didn't fix the issue.

Honestly speaking, I think I am completely stuck and not sure how I could address the issue.

What do you do if just one package doesn't support IE 11 browser?

Version

```
webpack: ^4.44.1
webpack-cli: ^3.3.12
webpack-dev-server: ^3.7.1
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer not to mix `include` and `exclude` constructions, there is a working option via regexp:

```js
    rules: [{
      test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  exclude: /node_modules(\/|\\)(?!(crypto|ws))/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    }]
```

Note: `ws` here just for example

Plus for some packages/functionality this code can be helpful (in case of IE11):

```js
if (!window.crypto) {
  window.crypto = window.msCrypto;
}
```